# Xcode -- Expand all macros in a file, without doing a full precompile?

Tags: xcode, macros, preprocessor

I am trying to read some code that has a lot of macros in it.  And often the macros are chained.  Is there any way to see a version of the file where all the macros have been expanded -- without doing a full run of the preprocessor (which would also do stuff like expand #imports)?  This would really help me read the code.

EDIT: Often the macros are defined in other files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best I can tell, the answer to my question is that there is no way to do it.  The best I can do is do a full precompile, then search for the part of the file that starts after all the #include statements.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a way to do this in Xcode, but you can use the compiler, specifically the -E option, which stops processing right after preprocessing.

```
cc -E foo.c
```

will print all the preprocessed results on stdout.  And

```
cc -E foo.c -o foo.preproc
```

will dump the preprocessed output into `foo.preproc`.